# wsgi django not working

Tags: python, django, wsgi

im installing django,

the test for wsgi is ok, but when i point my default file to the django test, it doesnt work,

this is the test that works fine:

default:     `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory /var/www/documents>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto/application.wsgi
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/djangoProj/mysitio/wsgi_handler.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

application.wsgi:: `~/djangoProj/micopiloto`

```
import os 
import sys 

sys.path.append('/srv/www/cucus/application') 
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/srv/www/cucus/.python-egg' 

def application(environ, 
start_response):

     status = '200 OK'

     output = 'Hello World!MK SS9 tkt kkk'

     response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),

                                     ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

     start_response(status, response_headers)


     return [output]
```

but if I change the default to point to `application_sa.wsgi` the django test,
it doesnt work :(

`application_sa.wsgi`

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto') 


os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'micopiloto.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I restart the apache server every time i change the wsgi to test,

so what im i missing?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your apache config to the following:

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myprocess processes=2 threads=15
    WSGIProcessGroup myprocess

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto/application_sa.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Then add the root folder of your project to sys.path as well in application_sa.wsgi:

```
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/djangoProj') 
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/djangoProj/micopiloto')
```

Comment: The key change likely making the difference being the sys.path changes.